# Evaluate $x^2\left(qy-rz\right)+y^2\left(rz-px\right)+z^2\left(px-qy\right)$, where variables are sines and cosines of $\alpha+2k\pi/3$

Tags: trigonometry, arithmetic-progressions

> Let $x$, $y$, $z$ be the sines of $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, and let  $p$, $q$, $r$ be the respective cosines, where the angles are in Arithmetic Progression with common difference $\frac{2\pi}{3}$.
>
> Find value of
>
> $$x^2\left(qy-rz\right)+y^2\left(rz-px\right)+z^2\left(px-qy\right)$$

My Attempt:
Let $\beta=\left(\alpha+\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)$ and $\gamma=\left(\alpha+\frac{4\pi}{3}\right)$

Given that
$$x=\sin\alpha \qquad p=\cos\alpha$$
$$y=\sin\left(\alpha+\frac{2\pi}{3}\right) \qquad q=\cos\left(\alpha+\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)$$
$$z=\sin\left(\alpha+\frac{4\pi}{3}\right) \qquad r=\cos\left(\alpha+\frac{4\pi}{3}\right)$$

Clearly,
$$x^2+p^2=y^2+q^2=z^2+r^2=1$$

Also, $$x+y+z=p+q+r=0$$

Now, there must be an algebraic identity which can help solve the problem.

Comment: Have u tried with $$xy(qx-py)$$

Comment: You are right.Thanks