# $x, y , z$ are respectively the $sines$ and $p, q, r$ are respectively the $cosines$ of the .....

Tags: trigonometry, arithmetic-progressions

$x, y , z$ are respectively the $sines$ and $p, q, r$ are respectively the $cosines$ of the angles $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, which are in A.P. with common difference $\frac{2\pi}{3}$. 
1. $yz + zx + xy = ?$ 
2. $x^2 (qy - rz) + y^2 (r - px) + z^2 (px - qy) = ?$
For the first I tried using the formula for $2sinAsinB$ but it is not helping. How do I solve them? Please, help.

Comment: What does the acronym "A.P." stand for?

Comment: @NobleMushtak Arithmetic Progression.

Comment: Is this a Mutiple choice type question or a broad-answer question?

Comment: $$\gamma=\beta+\frac{2\pi}{3}=\alpha+\frac{4\pi}{3}$$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1819828/evaluate-x2-leftqy-rz-righty2-leftrz-px-rightz2-leftpx-qy-right-wh

Comment: @Roman83 Yes. That's is what I'd used.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Sorry, but how does that answer my question?

Comment: I suggested the same hint : Start with $$xy(qx-py)$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I got it! Thanks! We can use the previous result to complete this one too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WLOG  let $x=\sin\left(A-\dfrac{2\pi}3\right),y=\sin A,z=\sin\left(A+\dfrac{2\pi}3\right)$

$$2(xy+yz+zx)=(x+y+z)^2-(x^2+y^2+z^2)$$

We can prove $x+y+z=0$

Using $\cos2B=1-2\sin^2B,$
$$2(x^2+y^2+z^2)=3-\left\{\cos\left(2A-\dfrac{4\pi}3\right)+\cos2A+\cos\left(2A+\dfrac{4\pi}3\right)\right\}$$

Now $\cos\left(2A-\dfrac{4\pi}3\right)+\cos\left(2A+\dfrac{4\pi}3\right)=2\cos2A\cos\dfrac{4\pi}3=?$